# Laravel : Return text/html as response

Tags: php, laravel, header, response, laravel-blade

In the laravel controller if someone wants to just send html as response and show it in the browser what is the best way to perform this action without any issue.

I want something like:

```
$html = "<html>-- All html document content --</html>"
// to show as html in browser.
return $html;
```

Comment: What's your laravel version?

Comment: My version : Laravel 6.2

Answer (score 3):

After some search I found a simple way, you can give any another way to perform this operation or if this is wrong way to do.

```
return response($html, 200)->headers('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

It worked on my machine.
Kindly do give more suggestions

Comment: I think your code in question was right! Maybe in laravel 6.2 this wont work but as I know in laravel 7+ it works